# Using the contents of a Textbox as arguments for Process.Start

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I'm trying to create a simple VB-application that would let me mount ISO files using the built in Windows PowerShell.

My Code is here:

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox1, "Looks Valid")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ErrorProvider1.GetError(TextBox1) = "Looks Valid" Then
        Process.Start("powershell", "Mount-DiskImage 'C:\ISO\MY Magic ISO.iso'")

    Else
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox1, "Please Select a Valid File")

    End If
End Sub
```

My program is simple, you pick a file from the dialog, and if the file is valid, it is mounted with powershell.

My question is how I would go about dynamically changing the "C:\ISO\MY Magic ISO.iso" filepath, using the contents of Textbox1. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am incredibly sorry if this has been asked before!

Comment: There's something about `If ErrorProvider1.GetError(TextBox1) = "Looks Valid" Then` that just looks conceptually wrong.

Comment: That said, have you tried using `TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: Hint: [concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx).

Comment: That's just it, I tried using that, but since it's within the quotation marks, everything I put inside does not get treated as code. I'm trying to figure out how I could get this to work...

Comment: I'm no VB-developer, but shouldn't this work? `Process.Start("powershell", "Mount-DiskImage '" & TextBox1.Text & "'")`?

Comment: So put additional quotation marks, so that you separate code and string! `"Mount-DiskImage '" & <file path here> & "'"`.

Comment: @FrodeF. : Great minds think alike, huh? Three seconds difference between our comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into pieces and use [Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) to combine them:

```
Process.Start("powershell", "Mount-DiskImage '" & TextBox1.Text & "'")
```

Sample:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim a As String = "C:\ISO\MY Magic ISO.iso"
        Process.Start("powershell", "-noexit -Command ""Mount-DiskImage '" & a & "'""")

    End Sub

End Module
```

Proof of success (or fail):

```
Mount-DiskImage : The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage 'C:\ISO\MY Magic ISO.iso'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], Ci
   mException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070003,Mount-DiskImage
```

Comment: This worked 100%, thanks to all of you guys who mentioned Concatenation, I'll definitely read up on that! :)